# Override @Html.Partial before it is rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am rendering Partial view inside a parent view

```
@Html.Partial("_OrderDetails.Info", Model)
```

But is it possible to override `_OrderDetails.Info` partial view with another partial view  before it is rendered ?

Is there method to use while partial view is rendered like we do in `ActionFilters` , `OnActionExecuting` ?

Comment: No (not unless you were to create you own extension method). Under what condition would you want to return a different partial, and why can you not put a conditional statement in the main view?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a simple `if` or `switch` to determine, which partial does get rendered?

Comment: @StephenMuecke , @Marco, Actually I am writing a plugin in `nopCommerce` , It's not best practice to change the core views, so i am trying alternate option, will custom view engine work as mentioned in [this](https://www.pronopcommerce.com/3-ways-to-display-views-in-your-nopcommerce-plugins-embedded-resource-theme-override-and-custom-view-engine) and [this](http://alexwolfthoughts.com/overriding-nopcommerce-admin-views-and-partial-views/) post ?

Comment: Have not had a change to look at the links, but other alternatives are to make it `@Html.Action()`to call a server method that returns the partial you want based on some condition. Or the partial could just conditional return the html you want based on some condition in the model.

Comment: @stom: *will custom view engine work as mentioned?* **Yes**

Comment: @Div , Thanks for the info, i will try in future, i have already found alternate solution by overriding parent view using action filters `OnActionExecuted` method as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416951/change-the-model-in-onactionexecuting-event).

Comment: @stom: Does it work really with the nopCommerce? I'm curious to know!!

Comment: @Div , actually it is not possible without using custom view engine. But in my situation what i did is i returned view from [action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507536/return-view-from-actionfilter) and in that view I used `@Html.Partial("_CustomOrderDetails.Info", Model)` to render my custom partial view. Hope helps.

Comment: @stom: Thanks! if you've time then add your answer, that may helps others!